# Как установить Monodevelop под Windows?

Tags: windows, mono, monodevelop

Понимаю, наверное, что тупой вопрос. Но куда ни зайду, везде ссылка на репозиторий GitHub c исходниками либо на [страницу](http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) , где есть ссылка для скачивания GTK и Mono, но не самой monodevelop. Туда же переадресация с monodevelop.com. И там же надпись:

> MonoDevelop for Windows is available from source only

Получается, если я хочу учтановить MonoDevelop на Windows, я должен скачивать исходники и компилировать? Неужели в сети нет ни одной откомпилированной версии?

Comment: Все бы хорошо, только при компиляции Main.sln куча ошибок и ненайденных библиотек. Например, куча неизвестных типов, как TextLocation, MethodDefinition и пр. Ненайденные пространства имен, например, ICSharpCode.NRefactory. Возможно, на них не подключена ссылка. Вот только откуда эти ссылки брать? Они что, не подключены изначально?

Comment: В readme написано просто +You can debug MonoDevelop using Visual Studio (on Windows or macOS) with the
+`main/Main.sln` solution. Use the `DebugWin32` configuration on Windows and the
+`DebugMac` configuration on macOS.

Comment: И все. 402 ошибки :)))

Comment: Нашел какой-то guid тут http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop// Попробую

Comment: Блин, там еще 79 проектов. Какой из них ставить запускаемым???

Comment: уже 538 ошибок)

Comment: Добавил через nuget xwt, NRefactory, Mono.AddIns (1.3.1), Ikwm.Reflection, Mono.Addins.Setup. Ошибок стало 13. Не могу найти Monodoc, а так же IKVM.Reflection.UniverseOptions не видит некоторые методы